# Node to Pod communication doesn't work on GCP by default

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, protocols, firewall

I am doing the CKAD (Certified Kubernetes Application Developer) 2019 using GCP (Google Cloud Platform) and I am facing timeouts issue when trying to `curl` the pod from another node. I set a simple Pod with a simple Service.

Looks the firewall is blocking something ip/port/protocol but I cannot find any documentation.

Any ideas?

Comment: I finally found a better place where I could ask questions: https://forum.linuxfoundation.org/categories/lfd259-class-forum

Answer (score 3):

So after some heavy investigation with `tshark` and google firewall I was able to unblock myself.

If you add a new firewall rule to GPC allowing `ipip` protocol for your node networks (in my case 10.128.0.0/9) the `curl` works !!

sources: https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

You can create nodeport service and use below command to set firewall rule.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-node-port --allow tcp:[NODE_PORT]
```

Then you can access service even from outside of cluster.

Comment: the problem I tried to solve is to be able to `curl` a pod from an internal node. Exposing the pod will not solve my problem.